# How to re-order the kendo rows by dragging and dropping

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

i want to re-order my rows using drag and drop functionality of kendo, rows are generated using Kendo, and i am able to drag, means i am able to grab a row, but when i drop it somewhere in the table, the rows position does not change it remains same.code from which rows are generated is

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid < WorkItemsGrid > ().Name("workItemsGrid").Events(e => e.DataBound("onDataBound"))
    .Columns(c => {

        c.Bound(i => i.Priority).ClientTemplate("#= GetArrow(Priority)#");
        c.Bound(i => i.Order);
        c.Bound(i => i.EpicTitle).Title("Epic");
        c.Bound(i => i.Type).ClientTemplate("#= GetType(Type)#");
        c.Bound(i => i.Code).ClientTemplate("#= SetEdit(ItemsId, Code)#");

        c.Bound(i => i.Title).ClientTemplate("#= length(Title)#");;
        c.Bound(i => i.State);
        c.Bound(i => i.Estimation).ClientTemplate("#= sum(Estimation)#");
        c.Bound(i => i.ItemsId).HtmlAttributes(new {
            @class = "rowId"
        }).Hidden();
    }).Scrollable().Reorderable(x => x.Columns(true))
    .DataSource(d => d
        .Ajax()
        .Read(r => r.Action("Get", "Items", new {
            projectId = ViewBag.projectId, selectedSprintId = ViewBag.selectedSprint
        }))
    )
);
```

Databound Javascrip:

```
function onDataBound(e) {

    var grid = this;
    var currentRecords = grid.dataSource.view();
    for (var i = 0; i < currentRecords.length; i++) {

        if (!currentRecords[i].activeInd) {
            var row = grid.tbody.find("tr[data-uid='" + currentRecords[i].uid + "']");
            row.addClass("item-row");

            row.draggable({
                cursorAt: {
                    left: 75
                },
                containment: ".grid-view",
                cursor: "-webkit-grabbing",
                start: function() {
                    $(this).hide();
                },
                stop: function() {
                    $(this).show();
                },
                helper: function() {
                    return $('<div id="' + $(this).find(".rowId").html() + '" class="holder k-grid"><table></table></div>').find('table').append($(this).clone()).end().appendTo('body');
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

How can change the order by dragging and dropping rows?
I am new to kendo, it was generated previously by some other developer which is not available today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/sortable/integration-grid) and refer to the [API documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/aspnet-mvc/kendo.mvc.ui.fluent/sortablebuilder). You can integrate the Kendo UI Sortable widget with the Kendo UI Grid.

Answer (score 1):

The kendo demo mentioned above will have issues when the grid is in in-cell edit mode - the changes to the cell are lost when another row is clicked.

This fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UsCFK/273/ works.

It uses a column with a drag handle as mentioned above to prevent cell edits being lost - the other cells are ignored in the setup:

```
grid.table.kendoSortable({
    filter: ">tbody >tr",
    hint: $.noop,
    cursor: "move",
    ignore: "TD, input",
    placeholder: function (element) {
      return element.clone().addClass("k-state-hover").css("opacity", 0.65);
    },
    container: '#grid tbody',
    change: onGridRowChange
});
```

It also updates the position field in the datasource, rather than removing, then re-inserting the row as in some other examples - as this will cause a delete request request to the server for each row that is moved - which can cause issues when clicking the batch-editing cancel button. The position field is only shown for demonstration purposes - it should not be exposed for manual editing.

Comment: I need to same thing in Vue with typescript is this possible